# getColumnIndex to access specific Folder in External Memory

Tags: java, android, android-cursor, mediastore, android-external-storage

I am attempting to show thumbnails in my gridview but I can't figure out how to only have my cursor access one specific folder called "FoMOvideos". How can I use 
.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
to access only one folder in my external storage?

```
private Uri getUriFromMediaStore(int position) {
        //int dataIndex = mMediaStoreCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
        int dataIndex = mMediaStoreCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "FoMOvideos");

        mMediaStoreCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        String dataString = mMediaStoreCursor.getString(dataIndex);
        Uri mediaUri = Uri.parse("file://" + dataString);
        //TODO: Figure out how to direct only to FoMO videos.
        //Uri mediaUri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/AppVideos" + dataString);
        return mediaUri;
    }

    private void getOnClickUri(int position) {
        int mediaTypeIndex = mMediaStoreCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE);
        int dataIndex = mMediaStoreCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "FoMOvideos");

        mMediaStoreCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String dataString = mMediaStoreCursor.getString(dataIndex);
        Uri mediaUri = Uri.parse("file://" + dataString);
        //TODO: Figure out how to direct only to FoMO videos.
        //Uri mediaUri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/AppVideos" + dataString);
```

I tried adding "FoMOvideos" the folder name to my dataindex variable but this results in the following error:

> 03-26 19:28:43.949 16399-16399/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                          Process: example.fadysi.fomoapp, PID: 16399
>                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.
>                                                              at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>                                                              at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
>                                                              at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>                                                              at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
>                                                              at example.fadysi.fomoapp.ThumbnailVideoPlay.MediaStoreAdapter.getUriFromMediaStore(MediaStoreAdapter.java:104)
>                                                              at example.fadysi.fomoapp.ThumbnailVideoPlay.MediaStoreAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MediaStoreAdapter.java:46)
>                                                              at example.fadysi.fomoapp.ThumbnailVideoPlay.MediaStoreAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MediaStoreAdapter.java:18)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6067)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6100)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5282)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:562)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3188)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3632)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1799)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
>                                                              at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                              at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
>                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:849)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
>                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
>                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
>                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
>                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
>                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
>                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.j

Comment: Found this solution:
https://cmsdk.com/java/how-to-set-mediastore-to-get-image-from-specific-folder-on-android.html

But I can't seem to get the following for loop to work properly:

List<String> sample = getFromSdcard();
    for(int i=0; i<sample.size() ; i++){
      final Uri image = Uri.parse("file://"+sample(i).toString());
    }

sample(i) is not recognized and requires a method.

Comment: Solved in another thread that I had posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335103/uri-parsefile-to-access-specific-folder